# How to ignore element to click although not visible Selenium

Tags: java, jquery, selenium

I am working on selenium, while running Java code I tried to access a text box from the web page but selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with Command duration or timeout error.

HTML code for text field :

```
<input type="text" name="TotalTaxPercent" id="TotalTaxPercent" value="19.00" class="smallinputField rightAlign" size="7" onblur="javascript:validateDecimal(this, 5)">
```

JAVA Code to access text field :

```
public void setItemTaxValue( String value){
  //By writableTag = By.name("TotalTaxPercent");
  By writableTag = By.xpath("//a[contains(@title,'Override total tax percent')]"); 
  this.sleep(3);
  if (this.waitForExistence(writableTag,35))    {
    this.textfieldSetText(writableTag, value);
    clickOnOK ();
    //          
  } else{
    JLog.fail("Unable to find a writable item taxdialog!");
  }         
}
```

> Error Tree :

```
[2015-07-14 20:18:34 PDT] Switch to Frame: <top>
[2015-07-14 20:19:22 PDT] Setting TextField (By.name: TotalTaxPercent) with data: 10
[2015-07-14 20:19:24 PDT] Screen Capture: C:\source\selenium-main\selenium-vodafone\target\capture\screenCapture_20150714201922308.jpg
[2015-07-14 20:19:24 PDT] FAIL: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 40 milliseconds
```

Kindly advise , Thanks you

Comment: before this i was using by.name however its not working neither i change to other to xpath method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just catch the Exception:

```
try {
  this.textfieldSetText(writableTag, value);
} catch (ElementNotVisibleException e) {
  JLog.fail("Unable to find a writable item taxdialog!");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably do entire action using JavaScript since it is a hidden field

```
String script = "document.getElementById('TotalTaxPercent').setAttribute('value','20.00');";
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript(script);
```

If JQuery is an option then try

```
String script = "$('#TotalTaxPercent').prop('value', 20.00);";
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript(script);
```

Comment: Hi Saifur , its not working . still getting the same error